# Pycharm: Unresolved reference 'True' in a docstring

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm

In the following code:

```
def f(x):
    """Return the argument
    :type x: bool
    :param x: the value to return.

    :rtype: bool
    :returns: the argument.

    Examples :
    >>>f(True)
   True
   """
return x
```

PyCharm thinks that 'True' in the line '>>>f(True)' is an unresolved reference. I do not understand why.

Below a screenshot of the code with the weak warning in yellow :

[image]

Comment: I do not get this error...

Comment: I have hit this issue too.  The common advice for this is to use File > Invalidate Caches / Restart, but this did not help me.  Same issue.  I am seeing it for both True and False values specifically in docstrings.  EDIT: You are not the only one - you are not going mad.

Comment: I also tested removing non-standard paths from the interpreter settings (File > Settings > Project (???) > Project Interpreter > Settings (gear button on right) > More > Paths button.  This had no effect either.

Comment: I also tried renaming ~/.PyCharm2017.1/system/python_stubs, but this did not make any difference.  FYI, I am running CentOS 7, and PyCharm professional.

Comment: I am running PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.2 and Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS.

Comment: Please update PyCharm, the issue is not reproducible in the latest EAP.

Answer (score 1):

This [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-24637) was reported, now it's fixed.